# Bootstrap modal issue on iOS 8.1.3

Tags: javascript, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue in Bootstrap Modal on iOS 8.1.3 version only. I have vertical scroll able div inside modal. When I touch the modal background then try to scroll the text inside that div, the text sometimes vanished or freeze then after few secs again I can scroll. Which is something weird. Any help will be really appreciable.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a demo of the problem in a fiddle? I think this may help https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839

Comment: Thanks for the reply cojomojo, I have tried that link which you have given. Also I have tried this "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3361" which didn't work too. Here is my code http://www.codeply.com/go/mP0LwPsHkZ

Comment: Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="parent">
  <h1>Modal a Different Way <small>Using CSS and JS</small></h1>

  <div class="child">
    <button class="cakeModalJS">Click Me!</button>
    <p>I have same behaviour what you have using to Modal concept except common UI issues.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cake-modal cake-hidden">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <button class="modal-close">x</button>
      <h3>
        Look I'm your inbuild Modal module 
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Cake Modal by Color Cake. All Right Recieved &copy; 2018</p>
  </footer>
</section>
$('.cakeModalJS').click(function(){
    $('.cake-modal').removeClass('cake-hidden');
});

$('.cake-modal').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  $('.cake-modal').addClass('cake-hidden');
});

$('.modal-close').click(function(){
    $('.cake-modal').addClass('cake-hidden');
});

$color1: #5b5b5b;
$color2: #fff;

@mixin btn-gray {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    border: 1px solid $color1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: $color2;
    &:hover{
     -moz-box-shadow:    inset  1px 0px 4px $color1;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset  1px 0px 4px $color1;
     box-shadow:         inset  1px 0px 4px $color1;
     text-shadow: 0.01px 0.01px 0.01px rgba(91, 91, 88, 0.4);
    }
}


.cake-hidden{
  display: none;
}
.parent{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  border: 2px solid $color1; 
  text-align: center;
  color: $color1;
  z-index: 1;
  h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    small{
      font-size: 40%;
    }
  }
}
.child{
  text-align: left;
  button{
    border: 1px solid $color1;
    padding: 10px;  
    cursor: pointer;
    @include btn-gray;
  }
  p{
    display: inline;
    color: $color1;
  }
}
.cake-modal{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: rgba(91, 91, 88, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
  .modal-body{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100vw/2);
    height: calc(100vh/2);
    background: $color2;
    z-index: 3;
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 0px 4px $color1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px $color1;
    box-shadow:         1px 0px 4px $color1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    padding:10px;
    h3{
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .modal-close{
      float: right;
      padding: 8px 8px;
      line-height: 10px;
      font-weight: 600;
      @include btn-gray;
    }
  }
}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  color:$color2;
  background: $color1;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  p{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain how this works and how it support the question.

Comment: Hi Chamath, Bootstrap Modal always have issues on mobile especially ios. I figured out that because of some CSS related to the position. So I did some own code that has exactly Modal behavior but it's a separate layer from body layer which is perfectly working on cross-browser and multi-devices, and you can implement anything on this layer.